# How to make jquery-ui buttons have same size for different browser

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, hyperlink, jquery-ui-button

I have jquery ui code for buttons as follows. I want these series of buttons to fit in same size (810px). They appear as same size for firefox and chrome but they look smaller in IE. I have try changing font size and having fixed width but it doesn't solve the problem. Anyone know how to fix it? Thank you.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#link" ).buttonset();

    });
</script>
<style>
#link{
   font-size: .74em !important;
   width: 810px;
   border: 1px solid #333;
}
</style>

<div id="link">
<a href="abc.php">ABC</a>
       <a href="efg.php" target="content">EFG</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use a css reset before loading any other css files on your page in order to standardize browsers. WHat you are seeing is that different browsers use different defaults for various properties such as font family and font size.

The jQuery UI css system mostly uses `em` sizing which therefore bases the font size, margins, padding etc on whatever the font size defaults are